# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:/cygwin/bin/bash": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, cygwin

I was Able to Run shell Script using Cygwin in java. But Now I am getting following message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:/cygwin/bi
n/bash": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

How to avoid this exception?

**Code**

```
{
            String cmd;
            cmd = "D:/cygwin/bin/bash -c'/bin/ls -la'";
            System.out.println("EXECING: " + cmd);
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            in = p.getInputStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            System.out.println("OUT:");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            in = p.getErrorStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            System.out.println("ERR:");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Try adding `.exe` onto the end of the file name?

Comment: Could you post the Java code that attempts to run `bash`.

Comment: Does D:/cygwin/bin/bash definitely exist? I have cygwin and ran this fine, with exception of changing the path to bash to "C:/bin/bash" and the -c argument to "-c /bin/ls -la".

Comment: Yes D:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe is present in the path

Comment: If you type `D:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "/bin/ls -la"` from a DOS prompt does it work?

Comment: Yes it woks Fine.it gives me output as list of files as "ls"

Comment: When you said "I was Able to Run shell Script using Cygwin in java", what was it that worked?

Comment: yes previously it was working fine but now i m getting this error I Restarted my system but still that error is coming

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5618/discussion-between-hmjd-and-niraj-deshmukh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended in a comment adding `.exe` would have resolved this but so did deleting the `bash.???` file.

There was a file named `bash.???` (I never found out what extension was) in the same directory as the `bash.exe` and the `Runtime.exec()` was attempting to execute it.

The `bash.???` must have been created at some point after a successful execution, hence it worked once and then failed.